# Возможны ли приватные функции в shell?

Tags: shell, zsh

Пишу функцию для zsh. Она должна использоваться постоянно, лежит в отдельном файле, он в `.zshrc` подключается строкой `source path/filename`.

Некоторые действия повторяются неоднократно, но копипастить код я не хочу. **Я хотел бы использовать несколько вспомогательных функций, но при этом не засорять общее пространство имен:**

- потому что хочу сделать портируемое решение, которое сможет использовать кто угодно. Другой пользователь должен знать имя основной функции, но не подозревать о вспомогательных.
- потому что автоподстановкой пользуюсь и лишние имена в ней не нужны.

Погуглил, вроде бы никаких приватных функций в shell'aх не предусмотрено. Что делать, как скрыть функции? Может быть, можно какие-то анонимные функции объявлять внутри основной?

Попробовал так:

```
foo() {
    bar() {
        echo "hello bar";
    }
    bar;

    fizz = () {
        echo "hello fizz";
    }
    fizz;
}

$ source filename
$ bar
hello bar
$ fizz
hello fizz
```

Похоже, что объявленная таким образом функция все равно доступна. Попробовал unset, как рекомендовано в аналогичном вопросе.

```
foo() {
    ...
    # пробую два разных синтаксиса
    unset $bar;
    unset fizz;
}

# первый ошибку выдает
$ foo
hello bar
hello fizz
foo:unset:10: not enough arguments

# а второй не работает
$ fizz
hello world
```

Comment: Связанный: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020444/how-to-unset-variables-after-use-in-zshrc. Но там функции с одноразовым использованием, не подходит.

Comment: Может, `unset bar` вместо `unset $bar`?

Comment: @VladD а все равно не работало

Comment: @NickVolynkin, мой варинт ответа не подошёл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновление: поскольку наш скрипт запускается самостоятельно, то он не оставит функций после себя. Поэтому самый простой путь, вероятно, такой:

```
[vladd@Kenga] [20:58:40] [~]
{0,378}$> cat install_functions.sh
#!/bin/bash

function bar() {
    echo "hello bar"
}

[vladd@Kenga] [20:58:49] [~]
{0,379}$> cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

. install_functions.sh

bar

[vladd@Kenga] [20:58:55] [~]
{0,380}$> ./script.sh
hello bar

[vladd@Kenga] [20:59:01] [~]
{0,381}$> bar
bash: bar: command not found
```

---

Например, можно попробовать так:

```
[vladd@Kenga] [20:38:38] [~]
{0,351}$> cat install_functions.sh
#!/bin/bash

function bar() {
    echo "hello bar"
}

[vladd@Kenga] [20:38:57] [~]
{0,352}$> cat remove_functions.sh
#!/bin/bash

unset -f bar

[vladd@Kenga] [20:39:03] [~]
{0,353}$> cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

. install_functions.sh

bar

. remove_functions.sh

[vladd@Kenga] [20:39:12] [~]
{0,354}$> ./script.sh
hello bar

[vladd@Kenga] [20:39:20] [~]
{0,355}$> bar
bash: bar: command not found
```

Это, однако, оставит пространство имён «грязным», если скрипт не отработает до конца. Поэтому наверное лучше делать всё в подшелле:

```
[vladd@Kenga] [20:43:11] [~]
{0,359}$> cat script2.sh
#!/bin/bash

( . install_functions.sh;
  bar
)

[vladd@Kenga] [20:43:19] [~]
{0,360}$> ./script2.sh
hello bar

[vladd@Kenga] [20:43:23] [~]
{0,361}$> bar
bash: bar: command not found
```

Возможно, имеет смысл сделать скрипт-загрузчик, который будет в подшелле загружать нужные библиотеки, и после этого запускать «основной» скрипт (переданный ему как параметр).

(Я не пробовал в zsh, но думаю, принцип отличаться не будет.)

Comment: Вернулся к этой задаче наконец-то. Я правильно понимаю, что функции нужно вынести в отдельный файл и подключать его через `.` в подшелле каждый раз, когда он нужен? С переменными ведь тоже такое сработает?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Угу, именно так.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Ну или если наш скрипт запускается отдельно, можно просто подключать функции без подшелла — скрипт ведь сам запускается в подшелле.

Comment: хм, завтра попробую понять.

Answer (score 1):

файл:

```
$ cat fun
foo() {
  (
    bar() {
      echo "from bar"
    }
    bar
  )
}
```

bash:

```
$ source fun
$ foo
from bar
$ bar
bash: bar: command not found
```

zsh:

```
$ zsh
$ source fun
$ foo       
from bar
$ bar       
zsh: command not found: bar
```

Comment: да, в под-оболочке (sub-shell).